# Pass variable to included playbook?

Tags: ansible

I would like to have a master playbook, which include's other playbooks.  Is it possible to pass a variable to that included playbook?

The normal syntax which is used for passing variables to included tasks doesn't work (see below)

```
- include: someplaybook.yml variable=value
```

and

```
- include: someplaybook.yml
  vars:
    variable: value
```

I'm running v2.0.2.0.

Comment: do you know about roles? what is this normal syntax that doesn't work?

Comment: As far as I know variables are global in scope for the duration of the entire run of the playbook so you just need to define the variables at any point

Comment: @Nasr Yes I know about roles--they won't help in this case.  I've added the normal syntax.  Ansible has different scopes for different types variables.  Simply using set_facts doesn't work.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR there are 3 variables scopes for at least Ansible 2.x according to the [official documentation here] (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes) and the global scope is only set by "config, environment variables and the command line".

Answer (score 4):

The only thing i see missing is quotes.

```
- include: someplaybook.yml variable='value'
```

It works for me and should work for you too. If not share the error you face.

Make sure you have this variable "variable" defined in the task of the role as well and from here you are just passing the value to that variable.

Comment: This works for task includes--not playbook includes.

Comment: In the above command i have included playbook. What do mean by task includes ? Can you please share the code where this variable is used so that i can get more info on how you want it to be used ?

Comment: Playbook includes are includes where the file you're including includes plays, i.e. they specify "hosts" machines and roles/tasks to run on those host machines.  Task includes just specify tasks to run.

Comment: This works for playbook include (as of 2020 at least), however you can only pass a static value in include itself, if you will try to pass variable the variable inside included playbook to which you passed it will be considered "NOT DEFINED".

Answer (score 4):

Tested on ansible 2.4

```
- import_playbook: any_playbook.yml variable='value'
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion most consistent way to pass variable to included playbook and to another play in the current playbook as well is using:

```
 set_fact:
      global_var_name: "{{ your_var }}"
```

before

```
 - import_playbook: your_playbook.yml
```

After you set the fact it's is accessible from any play in the playbook and imported playbooks, for instance inside "your_playbook" you can call it like so:

```
 debug:
      var: global_var_name
```

If you use:

```
 - import_playbook: someplaybook.yml variable='value'
```

you can only pass fixed 'value'(in include as well) if you try to pass var value:

```
 - import_playbook: someplaybook.yml internal_var="{{ your_var }}"
```

you will get NOT DEFINED when you call internal_var inside 'someplaybook.yml'

All of this is true for the beginning of 2021, ansible 2.9*, it's quite possible they will 'fix' import_playbook, I would like this, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Also, I suggest you read this,
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse.html
and try using roles in this case, it'll help in a case like this, where you're trying to include/import multiple playbooks in a single main playbook.
And about passing a value to the include statement you can add it to the vars main.yml of the role. 
Or, if the variable you want to pass is the result of a previous task in the single main playbook use 'register' and save the output in a varible.

`- debug: msg="{{result.stdout_lines}}"`

here, result is the registered variable.
Use the debug module to know exactly what you want to pass to the playbook. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't remember the exact context when I was asking this, but if you read the comments on the original question I was clear that roles could not be used to solve this.  I was already using roles--this was a slightly different use case than what roles could handle.  I forget the exact details though.